# Shell pass argument to java runned with arguments

Tags: java, linux, shell

I'm launching a java program from a shell script like this:

```
JAVA_OPTS=
CLASSPATH=
JMX_OPTS=
java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $JMX_OPTS
```

And launched program expects user to type another argument. It can't be specified in the list of arguments the program was launched with. So I wonder is there any way to pass this argument to a java program in a script?
I do not have the source of this java program, so I can't add an argument.

Comment: What exactly is `...`?

Comment: If user is expected to type then you should take input in the program.

Comment: Why can't you pass them as program arguments?

Comment: Because I don't have a source of a java program and because this is the way how this particular program is designed.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        System.out.println(args[i]);
}
```

Run your program:
java Name arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to pass an argument to the shell script. And in the script, pass it to the Java program. $@ may can achieve this.

```
java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $CLASSPATH $JMX_OPTS classname $@
```

Reference: [Passing arguments to a shell script](http://osr600doc.sco.com/en/SHL_automate/_Passing_to_shell_script.html)